# How to display my prefered column in Table Reference Widget

Tags: servicenow

Service Now - Service Portal : How can I set my preferred column name for search option display name in Table Reference Widget.

```js
/* Client Controller */
function ($scope) {
  $scope.table = "my_table";
  $scope.field = {};
  $scope.descriptor = {
    reference: $scope.table,
    attributes: '',
    name: '',
    searchField: 'my_field',
    qualifier: ''
  };
  
  $scope.valueSelected = function() {
    console.log($scope.field);
  }
}
```

```html
/* Body HTML Template */
<span>
      <sn-reference-picker
        sn-options="{placeholder: 'Search here'}"
                           ed="descriptor"
                           field="field"
                           sn-on-change="valueSelected()" />
    </span>
```

Above sample is from my cloned widget.
Let me know any suggestion on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of `display-field`, `display_fields`, and `search-fields`. Sadly the documentation on the ServicePortal is lacking.

- `display-field`: Main field to display on the line for the record
- `display-fields`: Sub fields that display below the `display-field`
- `search-fields`: Fields that you search on in the box

Try something like this to test on the *Incident* table.

**Template**

```
<sn-record-picker
    field="field"
    table="table"
    display-field="'short_description'"
    display-fields="'number,opened_at'" 
    default-query="'active=true'" 
    value-field="'sys_id'"
    search-fields="'number'"
    page-size="100"
    sn-on-change="valueSelected()">
</sn-record-picker>
```

**Client Script**

```
function ($scope) {
  $scope.table = "incident";
  $scope.field = {
    displayValue: $scope.data.short_description,
    value: $scope.data.sys_id,
    name: 'field'
    };

  $scope.valueSelected = function() {
    console.log($scope.field);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what the `ed` field is for with the OOTB version unfortunately.